# Creating account. How to use Keystore file

Tags: wallets, keystore

I'm currently creating an account and I just got my keystore file. I'm curious as to how I use this if my account is lost or I lost my password.

Do I have to use any of the text in the file or do I just use the file itself?

If I do have to use text in the file which set of number/letters and I using, its a little difficult to decode.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the full file. But you **need** the password. The keystore contains encrypted information, and it's encrypted with your password.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm curious as to how I use this if my account is lost or I lost my
>   password.

you'll need alongside this file your password. As this later is used to decrypt its information.

> Do I have to use any of the text in the file or do I just use the file
>   itself?

you need the whole file

Try to import your json file into mitamask, you'll be asked to provide your password otherwise your account won't be imported.